# Energy required to move an object at different speeds

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics, work

Does it take more or less energy to move/push a 500 pound cart over a distance of say 100 yards on a smooth surface at a speed of 5 mph versus a speed of 1 mph?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you two different types of answers; one where I answer this using only the provided information and using the standard assumptions for physics problems; with the other, I will make a series of assumptions that will stray slightly from the exact question you asked but will (I hope) better approximate an answer to the question I think you wanted to ask. Hopefully, seeing both answers will give you more experience with how to word a question in the clearest and most helpful way possible (I realize asking physics questions is an acquired skill and that expecting everyone to have it is unfair, so I'm legitimately trying to be helpful in doing this, not mean or patronizing).

To answer your question as asked:

A smooth surface is usually a physics term meaning it is frictionless. Assuming the surface is frictionless is usually an indicator that air resistance should be ignored as well. Since you are implying that the entire distance has to be covered at a certain velocity, we can assume that acceleration to that velocity has already been handled in a region not of interest for this given problem. Therefore, in the current construct, it takes exactly the same amount of energy to push the cart any distance at any speed. Let me be more clear, you are not required to push the cart at all; it takes zero energy. This is because without friction or drag and assuming the cart is already at speed, no force is required on your part. The cart will just keep going. Naturally, this isn't a very interesting result.

As you can see, the answer to the question as asked was not what you were looking for. Now, I'll answer what I assume you wanted to ask and include all my assumptions.

If we say it is on flat and level ground, but that we have to include air resistance and friction with the ground, then we have two ways we can approach this. We can choose either to have the cart already at speed (thus negating the need to apply force to get it up to speed), or we can say it starts from rest. To simplify the problem, I choose the former. The cart is already travelling at speed.

If this is the case, then when comparing two different speeds, when can ignore the effects of friction with the ground. This is because, in an idealized problem, the force of friction between the cart and the ground would be the same at all speeds, which means it doesn't contribute to differences in the energy. The only remaining thing that would slow the cart down (and thus require you to sustain a counteracting force) is air resistance. Since the force due to drag is proportional to the square of the velocity, $v^2$, this means that the faster you push the cart, the more drag it experiences. In order to keep the cart moving at the same speed over the whole 100 yards, you need to exactly oppose the drag force continuously (remember, we're ignoring friction). The more drag there is, the more force you have to apply.

Then, the amount of energy, $W$, it takes to move this cart any distance is found by multiplying the average force, $F$, you exert by the distance, $d$, over which it is applied. So if you have to sustain a higher force over the same distance, you have to do more work (it takes more energy).

$$W=Fd$$
$$F\propto v^2$$
$$\therefore W\propto v^2$$

So, in this situation, it takes more mechanical energy to push a cart at a larger velocity over any fixed distance.

That said, this is all just a calculation for the specific energy it takes to move the cart by any means. There are other things you could consider too. If you wanted to determine how much energy a human would need to expend, then you'd also need to figure out the energy expenditure from sustaining movement at each speed, the energy muscles require to continuously push the cart, etc. It's much more complex. In this scenario, air resistance is likely not going to be the most significant factor that makes higher speeds use more energy. But from a purely physics perspective, drag makes higher speeds eat up more energy

Comment: +1 a model for (some) other answers, including/especially my own